# Excel formula not working: date and number ranges

Tags: excel, formula

I have been trying to make this work in cell I1:

```
=IF(B18="","",IF(AND(OR(C16=7,C16="J",C16=8),B18< 300,D16< DATE(2021,5,15),300,IF(B18< 350),350,B18),(IF(AND(OR(C16=4,C16="T"),B18< 500),500,B18))))
```

Where:
if C16 is 7 or J or 8
and
the date in D16< DATE(2021,5,15)
and
B18<300
Result in I1=300 otherwise B18 (in case B18 is over 300).

Otherwise if D16> DATE(2021,5,15) and B18<350 I1=350.
If B18>350, I1=B18

Sorry...it looks messy!
R

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your formula and code don't align with each other.

But however, with the explanation you have provided, I could only write the following formula. Hope it works for you.

```
=IF( B18="" , "" , IF( AND( OR(C16=7,C16="J",C16=8), D16<DATE(2021,5,15) ) , IF(B18<300, 300, B18), IF( D16>DATE(2021,5,15) , IF(B18<350, 350, B18) ) ) )
```

Comment: This actually works for the first part:
=IF(B18="","",IF(AND(OR(C16=7,C16="J",C16=8),B18<300,D16<DATE(2021,5,15)),300,IF(B18<350,350,B18)))))

However it is missing this second part:
IF(AND(OR(C16=4,C16="T"),B18< 500),500,B18

Comment: You haven't mentioned that in your explanation. How am I supposed to know your conditions???

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it like this:

```
=IF(B18="","",IF(AND(OR(C16=4,C16="T"),B18<500),500,IF(AND(OR(C16=7,C16="J",C16=8),B18<300,D16<DATE(2021,5,15)),300,IF(B18<350,350,B18))))
```

Comment: Your formula doesn't meet all your conditions such as when b18> 300, as you yourself have mentioned in your explanation.